# cannot load CSVs or Excel files after some updates

Tags: python, numpy, statsmodels

I was trying to schedule a new python code by running with a BAT file, but was getting an error that the statsmodels package was not present.  The package loaded fine in Spyder, but not when running from a BAT file.  I followed a thread here that suggested updating my packages in console (pip command) which I did.

That led to a new error that NumPy was not loading.  I noticed that I now had 2 versions of NumPy (1.19.1 and 1.19.2).  Further searches yielded advise to uninstall and reinstall NumPy.  I had to uninstall twice to get rid of both versions, then installing left me with 1.19.2.

Now, when I run my code in Spyder, I get a strange error on pd.read_csv:

```
"Only callable can be used as callback"
```

I couldn't find anyone getting this error from pd.read_csv.  Next, I tried to run pd.read_excel in Spyder, but I get this error message:

```
"int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not '_NoValueType'"
```

This is code that worked fine yesterday on files that have not changed, so it is not the files.  I even made a couple test files and get the same error.  Trying to load statsmodels in Spyder now fails:

```
"from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import AutoReg"

"AttributeError: module 'numpy.core' has no attribute 'records'"
```

Running the same code in BAT, reading csv and excel files DO work, but still hangs up on loading statsmodels.

I think at this point, I need to reload Anaconda, but I don't understand why code that works in Spyder does not work running from BAT file, when I am referencing the only copy of python that I have in Anaconda.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be fine today, so perhaps I needed a full reboot to implement the updates?  I don't remember doing this in the past.

I'm still having the original issue with loading the statsmodels package when running from BAT file, but I will ask that in a new post.